# One of two coins chosen, tossed n times

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence, bayes-theorem

I am looking at the following problem about a coin toss experiment. I cannot understand the statements in the problem.

Problem statement is given below.

A drawer contains two coins. One is an unbiased coin,
which when tossed, is equally likely to turn up heads or tails. The other is a biased coin, which will
turn up heads with probability $p$ and tails with probability $1 − p$. One coin is selected (uniformly) at
random from the drawer. Two experiments are performed:

a) The selected coin is tossed $n$ times. Given that the coin turns up heads $k$ times and tails $n − k$
times, what is the probability that the coin is biased?

b) The selected coin is tossed repeatedly until it turns up heads $k$ times. Given that the coin is tossed
$n$ times in total, what is the probability that the coin is biased?

My confusion is that I cannot really figure out the difference between the two cases. Can you please help me understand the difference between the two cases?

Comment: for b) the last toss must be a head

Comment: If you let $k=0$, the difference is readily apparent: In the second case, you can only have $n=0$.

Comment: Yikes! Yes. You guys are right. I can accept it as an answer in case you wish to write a short answer for it.

Comment: In the second case we do not fix the number of tosses. Therefore it can be arbitrary. Moreover if the biased coin always  turns up tails, the second trial will never end for $k>0$. But I agree that my previous comment was not quite correct.

Comment: @user. Thanks and no problem about the previous comment. But when it comes down to solving the problem, I think it is as simple as what WW1 stated. The case b) must have the last toss as heads, while that is not the case in case a). But for that, analytically, there should not be any difference between the two cases.